# Visual Studio Code adds \\n when I paste code in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am a not an experienced coding person, and I am currently having problems when pasting code from Visual Studio Code

When I copy this from Visual Studio Code:

```
docker run -it \   --network=pgnet   t_ing:v001 \     --user=roll \     --password=roff \     --host=pg-db \     --port=5438 \     --db=nyta \     --table_name=yellow \     --url="${URL}"
```

It paste this in Mac's terminal:

```
\ndocker run -it \\n  --network=pgnet\n  t_ing:v001 \\n    --user=roll \\n    --password=roff \\n    --host=pg-db \\n    --port=5438 \\n    --db=nyta \\n    --table_name=yellow \\n    --url="${URL}"
```

And as a consequence the execution returns errors.

I have been deleting the `\\n`  each time, but that is annoying. How can avoid it?

Comment: I don't use Mac so I don't really have any idea what could be doing this, but to narrow down the problem, try copying from VSC into another application, like say TextEdit, and try copying from another application into the terminal.

Comment: From where in VSCode? `\n` normally denotes a new line, are you copying something with line breaks?

Comment: I am copying from a .yml tab in VSCode.

Comment: I'll bet you this is either due to your macos terminal app, or your shell. probably the terminal. not vscode.

Comment: You could automate the removal of the linefeeds from the contents of the clipboard.